# Can I ask “Actually?” instead of “Really?”

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

If someone says something and I would like to express my disbelief I would normally say “Really?”. An example would be someone says: “I won the lottery” - “Really?” or “I climbed the mount everest” - “Really?”. In those scenarios, would I be able to say “Actually?”. Would it be grammatically correct to express my disbelief, appreciation or request for reconfirmation  by saying “Actually?” instead of “Really?” ?

Answer (score 2):

A fluent English speaker would most likely understand what you meant, but it would sound strange, since "actually" is pretty much never used that way.

Some alternatives to "Really?" include "Seriously?", or perhaps "No way. Are you kidding me?"  There are actually quite a few.